# Auto Serial Number in Datatables along with responsive tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am unable to integrate auto serial number 
https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html

with responsive table type
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/fixedHeader.html

Please tell me which attributes I need to change in Javascript to have both scripts in one table

Ps. please be little explanatory I am from non-tech background
any compilation of code (jsfiddle) will be appreciated

Also can auto serial numbers be sortable?

If I try adding scripts of both types it ends up in an error

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">  

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true
    } );

    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table );
} );

    </script>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#example2').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        } ],
        "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );

    t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        } );
    } ).draw();
} );


    </script>
```

I even tried changing the class to example and example2
didnt work
pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working sample that includes both `index_column`, `responsive` extension and the `fixedHeader` extension all working together.

Your Question: ***Also can auto serial numbers be sortable?***

No. Directly from the documentation:

> This column should not be sortable, and will change dynamically as the
>   ordering and searching applied to the table is altered by the end
>   user.

[Reference](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html)

The most important parts of the code below are the stylesheet and javascript references in the HTML file and this line of code that turns on the `fixedHeader`:

```
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table );
```

Hope that is enough explanation for you.

NOTE: if you are not familiar with this site, hit the [Run Snippet] button. Then you can click [full page] on the right. That will allow you resize to see the responsive extension is working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    paging: true, // works with or without paging
    columnDefs: [{
      searchable: false,
      orderable: false,
      targets: 0,
    }],
    order: [
      [1, 'asc']
    ],

  });
  new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);

  table.on('order.dt search.dt', function() {
    table.column(0, {
      search: 'applied',
      order: 'applied'
    }).nodes().each(function(cell, i) {
      cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
    });
  }).draw();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>$313,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>$385,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Michael Silva</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>$198,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>$725,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Gloria Little</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>$237,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Bradley Greer</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>$132,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Dai Rios</td>
        <td>Personnel Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>$217,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
        <td>Development Lead</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>$345,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Yuri Berry</td>
        <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>$675,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Caesar Vance</td>
        <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>$106,450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Doris Wilder</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>$85,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
        <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>$1,200,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>$92,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>$357,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>$206,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Fiona Green</td>
        <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>$850,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Shou Itou</td>
        <td>Regional Marketing</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>$163,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Michelle House</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>$95,400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Suki Burks</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>$114,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>$145,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
        <td>Team Leader</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>$235,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Martena Mccray</td>
        <td>Post-Sales support</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>$324,050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Unity Butler</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>$85,675</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>$164,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
        <td>Secretary</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>$109,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>62</td>
        <td>$452,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>$136,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>$645,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Olivia Liang</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>$234,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Bruno Nash</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>$163,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>$139,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Thor Walton</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>$98,540</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Finn Camacho</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>$87,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
        <td>Data Coordinator</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>$138,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>$125,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>$115,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
        <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>$75,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Cara Stevens</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>$145,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Hermione Butler</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>$356,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Lael Greer</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>$103,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>$86,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Shad Decker</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Michael Bruce</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Donna Snider</td>
        <td>Customer Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>$112,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: worked in an instant! thank you so much Randy :) you're a legend.